# Define a string that spans multiple lines

Tags: r, string

When string literals span multiple lines, one can use triple-quotes `"""..."""` in python.

```
>>> string = """\
... Usage: thingy [OPTIONS]
...      -h                        Display this usage message
...      -H hostname               Hostname to connect to
... """
>>>
```

Is there any possible way like this in R?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

R strings also support such behavior:

```
string <- "
    ... Usage: thingy [OPTIONS]
    ...      -h                        Display this usage message
    ...      -H hostname               Hostname to connect to
    ... "

print(string)
```

**Output:**

```
[1] "\n... Usage: thingy [OPTIONS]\n...      -h        
            Display this usage message\n...      -H hostname 
          Hostname to connect to\n... "
```

Comment: You probably want to use `cat(string)` because `print` escapes the output.

Comment: @Eumenedies Point taken, but that might depend on what the OP plans to do with the string.  Seeing the literal newlines in there lets us know that R has recorded the multiple lines.